# Understanding java/apex complex ternary operator

Tags: javascript, java, apex, apex-code, conditional-operator

This is apex code, but for the propose seems to work like in Java or JScript.

I've the following line of code (comment included):

```
// If GPMIR_fld_codigoOrigen__c 09 Fotofactura will not be assigned to agency for send csv

eLead.GPMIR_fld_assignAgency__c = (eLead.GPMIR_fld_codigoOrigen__c!='09') ? ((u.Contact != null && u.Contact.Account != null && rt == 'Agencia') ? u.Contact.Account.Id : null) : null;
```

Trying to **translate** that to **regular if-else** what i think it's happening here is (comment included):

```
// If GPMIR_fld_codigoOrigen__c != 09 then GPMIR_fld_assignAgency__c == null

if(eLead.GPMIR_fld_codigoOrigen__c!='09'){
    if(u.Contact != null && u.Contact.Account != null && rt == 'Agencia'){
        eLead.GPMIR_fld_assignAgency__c = u.Contact.Account.Id;
    }else{
        eLead.GPMIR_fld_assignAgency__c = null;
    }
}else{
    eLead.GPMIR_fld_assignAgency__c = null;
}
```

Probably i'm wrong but **if anyone could help me to do the proper translation** i would really appreciate it

Comment: `(A) ? ((B) ? C : null) : null` is the same as `((A) && (B)) ? C : null` --- Anyway, **you're right**, that is the equivalent `if-else` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems correct, but You can also do this inside a function

````
Public string MyFunction(){
 if(eLead.GPMIR_fld_codigoOrigen__c!='09'){
    if(u.Contact != null && u.Contact.Account != null && rt == 'Agencia'){
        Return u.Contact.Account.Id;
    }
}
Return null;
}```
//Then in main(), eLead.GPMIR_fld_assignAgency__c = MyFunction()
````

Hopefully I'm right as well.